# How to determine if markers are overlapping visually in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, collision-detection

To be clear, this is about overlapping markers *visually* not by lat/lng. I'm not looking for clustering or spidering.

How to determine, in this case, 1 and 3 are overlapping and not 2

[image]

In my case the icons can be varying sizes and shapes. Lat/Lng wont be useful because they could (in theory) be 1000mi away and still overlap. Normally I could do this with getting the CSS positioning and image size and do the math if it's overlapping but I'm not sure how I can only do it with everything in Google Maps referencing these objects in Lat/Lng positioning.

Comment: It was marked as too broad, but no comment. I can try to be more clear but to me this isn't too broad. It's very specific: how to determine if the pixels of 2 markers are overlapping.

Comment: I believe you can do this by reading the pixel coordinates of the markers (which of course varies by scale). Then compare them and decide if they overlap, using what knowledge you have about the marker size (constant pixel size).

Comment: There is some code her https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates that shows the basics of finding pixel location of things at known geo-locations.

Comment: I stumbled on this also - a bit old but is right on topic. http://www.optimit.hr/hr/blog/-/blogs/optimizing-icon-position-with-google-maps-api